# How to clean files without calling "make clean" in makefile.am (automake)

Tags: makefile, automake

I have makefile.am. I want to clean the files without using "make clean" in automake file.

After building, .la, .a, .so files will be generated. I want to remove all the files. If I run make clean, then those will be removed. 
But, I need them to be removed at the end of make.

makefile.am:

```
libdir=${prefix}/lib/cli

lib_LTLIBRARIES= libmain.la

libmain_la_SOURCES = main.c

clean-local:

             rm -f *.la
             rm -f *.a
```

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this.  Why do you need this though?

Comment: This doesn't make sense: If you just ran `make`, you would immediately 'clean' everything that's been built.

Comment: Hi Tom, I need to clean only static files and object file. This has to be done at the end of make.. (Once everything has been completed)..